# Do I need to be enrolled in Apple Developer Program to publish apps as a part of organization

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program

I have an apple account that is NOT enrolled in Apple Developer Program. I became a member of another organization using their invitation and they gave me the role of "Admin" in iTunes connect.

However, I do not see the option of publishing application to app store from iTunes connect when I am logged in using my apple account.

Question:

1. Do I have to pay 99 bucks to be able to publish apps on app store even though my apple account is a part of this organization.
2. If 1 is true, then why is apple charging me again even though the organization have already paid them.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to be enrolled in Apple Developer Program personally if your Apple ID is a member of an organisation which has already enrolled. Speak to your organisation if you seem to be unable to publish apps under their program membership.

Comment: May be I am missing something then. When I go to developer console>itunes connect>apps. I do not see any options to publish the apps, it takes me to a page which says "Get started" for Apple Developer Program.